# Appending existing onClick value

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am using javascript and need to grab the value of an existing onclick and append to it.  I am not trying to replace the current onclick, I am trying to append to the front, or end, of it.  But all different iterations of this effort are failing.

Quick example:

```
<pre>
<a href="blah" id="tabA" onclick="alert("this");"
<script>
   function test() {
      alert("that") ;
   }
document.getElementById('tabA').onclick = "test();" + document.getElementById('tabA').getAttribute('onclick') ;
</script>
</pre>
```

Comment: I have the contents of the current onclick...still can't figure out how to prepend it with the new content (js code) though

Answer (score 0):

When using the .onclick event you should use function and then the action:

```
document.getElementById("tabA").onclick = function()
{
alert("hello world")//this will work
}

document.getElementById('tabA').onclick = "test();" + document.getElementById('tabA').getAttribute('onclick') ;//fail since events are not variables to store values.
```

So, what you whatever you are tring to do, in that way it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I had got your point.
My solution is

```
    <a href="blah" id="tabA" onclick="alert('this');">tabA</a>
    <script>
       function test() {
          alert("that") ;
       }
       var oldClick = document.getElementById('tabA').getAttribute('onclick') ;
       var newClick = function(){
            test();
            eval(oldClick);
       }
    document.getElementById('tabA').onclick = newClick;
    </script>
```

when I click the 'tabA', it alerts 'that' then 'this'.
http://jsfiddle.net/x3Xds/

Comment: chard, your solution almost has me there.  I was able to redefine the onclick, however I tested for the new value of the new onclick and all I would see is "function(){ test(); eval(oldClick); }" - I wouldn't actually see the old onclick code nor would the orig/old onclick code execute.  I even tried <pre>var newClick=function(){ test();oldClick(); }.   Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but, I needed to do the same thing.

I got around this by using an event;

```
obj.addEventListener('click', function(){ test(); }, false);
```